# How do i change SVG image color dynamically which is set at the background of my canvas

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have an SVG file for the background of my canvas. I want to change the fill colour of this svg file dynamically. Can any one please help me? I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be possible in your case for whatever reasons:
Could you make the background of your svg transparent? This way you could easily change the background color of the canvas.

Comment: i want to change path color of my svg image which is possible if i take svg image inside canvas but i want to do same thing for my background svg image, any idea how ?

Comment: i already use transparent svg images i only want to change fill color of paths on this svg file